# Print SSRS .rdl report with parameters from c# Console

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am writing a c# console application that needs to print a report as part of my solution. I downloaded MS-Report Builder and created a report that needs a parameter from the C# console application. I did not install the 'web based ssrs'. I then added the .rdl file to my console application solution.

My question is: Is there a way to print the rdl file with a parameter directly from the c# console application or create a pdf in a specific file location?

I have tried looking at many sources online to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some console code that opens the report, add parameters and finally save to file system.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get connection from config file
            var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks2016ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            // Add report parameter
            String paramValue = "Design Engineer";
            ReportParameter jobTitleParam = new ReportParameter("JobTitleParam", paramValue);

            // Add same parameter to sql script
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM HumanResources.vEmployee WHERE JobTitle = @JobTitleParam", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobTitleParam", paramValue));
            
            // Populate table with data
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
            table.TableName = "Employees";

            // Initialize report viewer with report and set report parameters
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(jobTitleParam);
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
            
            // Add data source to report
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", table);
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

            // Render report to PDF and save to file system
            String deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts></DeviceInfo>";
            byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"c:\output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Flush();
            }


        }
```